# Professional Camera worth ($14000) needs insurance on travel to Japan

Tags: international-travel, insurance

I'm looking for travel insurance for my camera and equipment which is worth a significant amount of money while traveling to Japan. I've looked at World Nomads, AIG, travelguard but they they don't cover the cost of the camera. I'm hoping to get suggestions from travelers who have successfully claimed insurance for such expensive equipment. (I live in the US)

Comment: How do you insure it at home ? My (home) insurer covers theft and damage to my gear even abroad.

Comment: I'm thinking a $14k camera should have extensive insurance to begin with, not only if you travel with it.

Comment: If you're a professional photographer, you presumably should have insurance for your business. Whoever wrote that policy is the one to ask.